# Simple mod_rewrite rule is not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In my main public directory, I have this .htaccess file, however when visiting `/register` I get a 404 error.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php
```

With this, I want to make anyone who visits `/register` to use `/register.php`. I am certain that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and `AllowOverride All` is present in my virtual host file.

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this? All I get is `The requested URL /register was not found on this server.`

Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@email.com

        ServerName my.site.com
        DocumentRoot /home/mark/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/mark/public>
                Options All MultiViews ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/mark/logs/public_error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /home/mark/logs/public_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And when you go to `http://yourdomain.com/register.php`, you don't get a 404?

Comment: And are you sure you aren't going to a URL that ends with a `/`?

Comment: Yes. I get a 404 with and without a trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <Directory /home/mark/public>
            Options All MultiViews ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

You need to turn **off** [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews):

```
            Options All -MultiViews ExecCGI
```

It's messing with optional content negotiation. From the apache documentation:

> If the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that document.

If you're going to have a rule to rewrite `/register` to `/register.php`, you don't want MutliViews mucking things up before it even gets to your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ....
</VirtualHost>
```

> /var/www/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/register$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ register.php [NS,L]
```

EDIT: added DocumentRoot /var/www

Comment: Then what does your virtual host file look like

Comment: run `a2enmod rewrite` see what it says and then then restart

Comment: No, it didn't. Already tried force-refreshing and accessing on different browsers.